# How do I see the value of a mutt configuration option?

Tags: mutt

When trying to debug my mutt configuration, I needed to see what was the value of some configuration setting in a running `mutt` process. How do I figure out what is the current value of a variable in `mutt`?

Answer (score 23):

Run `enter-command` (by default it is bound to `:` in the index view) and then run `set ?option`, where `option` is the desired option; `mutt` will then display what is the current value for the option.

Source: [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#set-commands).

Comment: Upvoting both question and answer because I've been using Vim for so long that I keep thinking the question mark comes *after* the name of the variable and I come back to this question when that doesn't work.